# NextAuth - Added Gooogle Provider to NextAuth setup that comes with t3app, but the button doesnt show on signin page

Tags: next.js, next-auth, t3-app

So i have email and discord working, but my customer base doesnt really use discord, they are using facebook and google as their main sso provider.

Discord provider was nice to get the POC working, but now im running into an issue where the following is happening:

I comment out Discord, the button is still there??? it just doesnt do anything.

I add Facebook and Google Providers, but they dont show up at all.

if i setup a custom page to see what im getting back from nextauth, using the documentation suggested method for pulling providers

`const providers = await getProviders();`

When i see the response array, it has email and discord only,  even though discord has been commented out, and I dont see facebook or google there, or any other provider that I add, always email and discord.

If i add my own trigger manually:

```
 <Link href="#!" onClick={() => signIn("google")}>
      Sign in with Google
    </Link>
```

it works fine, so the authOptions definitely has the information and its able to properly complete the auth flow and generate session + token, its just the getProviders method doesnt return all the actual values that are in the authOptions config.

What am I missing? I confirm the env vars are available (console log them and values come up). I confirm the flows actually work if I trigger them manually through a link comp onclick sign in with auth provider name. I confirm the callback uri works since it returns me as signed in and all auth pages work as expected.

Very confused why its showing the discord button, but not any other providers I added especially if i have disabled discord as provider, getProviders response still has only email and discord....

Is there some caching happening? Seems like really odd behavior.